# Inserting into a MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on this problem for two hours. I'm most likely just missing something incredibly obvious. Basically, I can't get either of these queries to actually insert into the server. 
I've added the data to the server manually, and it gives no problems.
My other scripts *are* successfully adding things to the server.
I've used the ping function to confirm I'm connected to the server.
And I've also gone through the list of inputs to make sure nothing unexpected is being added.

I don't know what else to try.

```
$Name = $_POST['Project_Name'];
$Description = $_POST['Description'];
$Languages = $_POST['Languages'];
$dateposted = $_POST['DatePosted'];
$Spots = $_POST['Spots'];
$Comments = $_POST['Comments'];
$PostingUser = $_SESSION['UserID'];

if(!empty($Name) AND !empty($dateposted))
{
    mysql_query("
INSERT INTO Project
(ProjName
, Slots
, CurrentSlots
, Date_Posted
, Languages
, ProjDescription
, ProjType
, Comments
, AddingUser
) VALUES
('$Name'
, '$Spots'
, '0'
, '$dateposted'
, '$Languages'
, '$Description'
, NULL
, '$Comments'
, '$PostingUser')
");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO PostedBy(fk_pb_ProjName, fk_pb_Username)VALUES('$Name', '$PostingUser')");
    header("refresh: 1; url=Add-Project.html");
    echo " Project Submitted. Returning to main list.";
}
?>
```

That's the PHP code, and here's the two SQL tables.

Project:

```
CREATE TABLE Project
(
  ProjName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  Slots INT NOT NULL,
  CurrentSlots INT,
  Date_Posted VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  Languages VARCHAR(40),
  ProjDescription VARCHAR(255),
  ProjType VARCHAR(10),
  Comments VARCHAR(255),
  AddingUser VARCHAR(7),
  FOREIGN KEY (AddingUser) references Users(Username),
  PRIMARY KEY(ProjName)
);
```

PostedBy:

```
CREATE TABLE PostedBy
(
  fk_pb_ProjName VARCHAR(100),
  fk_pb_Username VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (fk_pb_ProjName),
  FOREIGN KEY (fk_pb_Username) references Users(Username),
  FOREIGN KEY (fk_pb_ProjName) references Project(ProjName)
);
```

This is my first time doing anything substantial with PHP and MySQL, so I'm most likely overlooking something incredibly simple.

Comment: stop using the depricated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Comment: You have to check for errors. after executing queries.

Comment: Professor is requiring us to use mysql for reasons known only to him.

Comment: you should use pdo or mysqli. in PDO, you can bind dates with PDO::PARAM_STR.

Comment: And here is a nice tutorial for [PDO](http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/09/introduction-to-pdo.html)

Comment: @DiskElemental the reason is simple, he doesn't know any of the newer libraries and does not feel the need to update. That's sad and you should report this to the principal.

Comment: Heh. Believe me, using MySQL is the least of the guy's problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO PostedBy(fk_pb_Name, fk_pb_Username)VALUES('$Name', '$PostingUser')"
```

and in your table definition:

```
fk_pb_ProjName VARCHAR(100),
```

These do not match.

Apart from that: (after switching to mysqli or PDO) read up on displaying MySQL errors and prin them out.

EDIT:
For mysqli, check : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: D'oh. Wasn't aware you could print errors through PHP. That would have saved me a whole lot of time.

Comment: Aaaaand that helped my find the solution in less than 5 minutes. Turns out one of my inputs wasn't sanitized and was screwing up the entire rest of the system.

Answer (score 4):

OLD

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO Project(ProjName, Slots, CurrentSlots, Date_Posted, Languages, ProjDescription, ProjType, Comments, AddingUser)VALUES('$Name', '$Spots', '0', $dateposted, '$Languages', '$Description', NULL, '$Comments', '$PostingUser')");
```

AND NEW

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Project(ProjName, Slots, CurrentSlots, Date_Posted, Languages, ProjDescription, ProjType, Comments, AddingUser)VALUES('$Name', '$Spots', '0', ------->'$dateposted'<-----, '$Languages', '$Description', NULL, '$Comments', '$PostingUser')");
```

Be sure to put the single quotes over every variable that you are going to query! i think thats the problem anyways.. Go to your date posted variable this is where the problem should live

Comment: Why did you have to format a PHP function call as HTML language and a Javascript snippet? I'm talking about `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->` and `<!-- language: lang-html -->` which just make your answer more difficult to read.

Comment: Still new to this as you might be able to see by badges etc  ^_^ thank you for your concern could you tell me how to do it properly..?

Comment: It looks better now. Basically, unless you have any special requirements you can just add 4 spaces before the code and that is enough for Stackoverflow to display it correctly.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem, but thanks for catching that.

Comment: I also noticed that in table PostedBy you have the fields fk_pb_ProjName and fk_pb_Username but when you do the insert query you are trying to insert into fk_pb_Name